# Overflow Scroll using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I make the `div` as `parent` and inside the `parent div` i make sub `child div` which is of content.
Everything works perfect but my question is, I make the the `parent div` as `overflow:scroll` 
Like

```
#testing {
    width:400px;
    height:390px;
      background:steelblue;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

It appear like this here
[image]

You can see this picture.
Overflow scroll is looks like this way appear :( see this in right side and bottom of image with arrow)
Why this should happen on using `overflow:scroll` I don't want this view scroll should appear only if the content exceeds the div. I am not sure how to do this.
http://jsfiddle.net/ShvzM/4/

Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just have to do...

```
overflow:auto;
```

for

```
#testing {
  width:400px;
  height:390px;
  background:steelblue;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

***[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShvzM/5/)***

Answer (score 4):

Use `overflow: auto`. This only shows the scroll bars when the content exceeds the boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set `overflow` to `auto`. `overflow` when set to `scroll` will always display the scroll bars. When set to `auto`, the scrollbars are displayed only when needed.

You can find more information about the `overflow` property in this [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

Answer (score 3):

Change it in your css

```
#testing {
    width:400px;
    height:390px;
      background:steelblue;
    overflow:auto;        <----------- Not scroll
}
```

Why `auto`, because so it will only appear when you have to much height or width.
Else with `scroll` it will give you both scrolls `vertical` and `horizontal`.

Answer (score 3):

if you want horizontal scroll then use ***overflow-x: scroll*** and if vertical then use ***overflow-y: scroll***. If you want scroll bars only when content exceeds the div's width then use ***overflow: auto***